# making a batch file run hidden/minimized without modifying the shortcut

Tags: batch-file, hidden, minimized

I'm writing an application in VB.net that creates and calls batch files. I'd like these batch files to run hidden, but since there will be no shortcuts for the files, I would need to set this in the batch code itself. How would I do this?

Comment: See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/62525/run-a-completly-hidden-batch-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the vbs script in the link looks good, but if you are calling the batch files from the VB app then you can run the batch files hidden:

```
Dim p As New Process()
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C mybatchfile.bat"
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
p.Start()
p.WaitForExit();// this line waits for the batch to finish, remove if you want to start the batch and continue your app while it runs.
```

Martyn